# ¿Por qué perl no detecta el módulo que he creado?

Tags: perl

Como podéis observar en el título, no sé el porqué pero por alguna razón perl no me detecta el módulo que tengo en el mismo directorio donde está el *script*.

Cuando intento abrir el *script* de Perl me dice lo siguiente:

```
Can't locate (el nombre del modulo).pm in @INC
```

He intentado hacer todo lo que he podido para intentar hacer que me pille el módulo pero no he conseguido nada... sigo con el mismo mensaje.

Comment: Y como importas el modulo??donde esta tu código?? Ten sentido común, no somos adivinos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En las últimas versiones de Perl se ha eliminado el directorio local ('.') de la lista de rutas donde perl va a buscar los módulos, por motivos de seguridad. La lista la puedes ver con el comando `perl -V`.

Para decirle que la busque en el directorio actual, basta con agregarlo a @INC al principio del programa, con la sentencia `use lib ".";`

Mejor aún si pones la ruta completa al directorio donde se encuentra el módulo.

Más información en http://perlenespanol.com/tutoriales/modulos/usar_modulos_sin_instalar.html

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.